# Aborting ngResource using a promise object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise, angular-resource

I've recently learned that ngResource request can be aborted either by specifying a timeout in ms or passing a deferred object.

The second solution does not seem to work for me, and I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. I've created a fiddle to demonstrate the problem http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/10977/

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',['ngResource']);

myApp.factory('myResource', function($resource) {
    return {
      getResource: function (aborter) {
        var resource = $resource(
            'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk', {}, {
          query: {
            isArray: false,
            timeout: aborter.promise
          }
        });

        return resource;
      }
    };
});

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $q, $log, $timeout, myResource) {
    var aborter = $q.defer();
    setTimeout(function() {
       $log.info('Aborting...');
       aborter.resolve();
    }, 10);
    myResource.getResource(aborter).query().$promise.then(function(data) {
        $scope.data = data;
    });
});
```

I want to avoid sending multiple request at the time (I want to cancel the previous by calling `aborter.resolve()`.

I was following this solution [Angular $http : setting a promise on the 'timeout' config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21915834/angular-http-setting-a-promise-on-the-timeout-config)
Could you please advice me why it does not work?

Comment: Apparently, it's not doing what you think it does when you pass a promise to $resource method: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/7974

Comment: It looks like it's an open issue with Angular 1.3: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/9332 You're jsfiddle works if you drop back to 1.2.28.

Comment: @BradBarber thanks, that's the issue, please make your comment an answer so I can give you +100

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like it's an open issue with Angular 1.3: [github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/9332](http://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/9332) You're jsfiddle works if you drop back to 1.2.28.

Comment: An update: It seems like this fix will be merged in 1.4.8 https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/12657

Answer (score 0):

Try using `$timeout`, instead of `setTimeout`, since that will take care of making sure your resolve is captured by angular `$digest` cycle.

```
myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $q, $log, $timeout, myResource) {
    var aborter = $q.defer();
    $timeout(function() {
       $log.info('Aborting...');
       aborter.resolve();
    }, 10);
    myResource.getResource(aborter).query().$promise.then(function(data) {
        $scope.data = data;
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for you input, but I've tried that one as well http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/10983/

Answer (score 0):

try to change this line of ngResource source code:

`httpConfig[key] = copy(value);`

in

`httpConfig[key] = key !== 'timeout' ? copy(value) : value;`

the problem is the copied promise