# How to cancel a $resource request in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a ajax call like this

```
    angular.module('my.module')
    .factory('Users', ['config', '$resource', function(config, $resource) {
      return $resource('/my/endpoint', {
        userId: '@userId'
      }, {
        query: {
            method: "GET"
        }
    });
  }])
```

then I have a UserLoader

```
.factory('UserLoader', ['Users', 'LoaderFactory', function(users, LoaderFactory) {
   [some other stuff]
}])
```

and the the controller

```
.controller('UserSearchCtrl', ['$scope', 'UserLoader', function($scope, UserLoader) {

}])
```

how can I cancel a previous call before to send another?

Comment: look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21666960/how-to-cancel-resource-requests

Comment: I saw it but I am not in a controller and I don't know how to convert it for a factory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to configure your resource as cancellable

```
query: {method: 'get',cancellable: true}
```

Then you can call `$cancelRequest()` on this resource.

```
Users.query().$cancelRequest()
```

Comment: from my controller? How?

Comment: How do you require and use your factory? Maybe I can help if you share the code

Comment: I have another factory called UserLoader, that refers to Users. then userLoader in injected in the controller

Comment: You can return `Users.query()` from `UserLoader` and by doing this you will have access to request object

Comment: UserLoader  is currently returning an instance of LoaderFactory, how can I embed Users.query()? However, I am able to access Users from the controller adding it in the signature, but calling Users.query().$cancelRequest() gives me non-existing method. Can you provide an example?

Comment: marked this answer as correct. solution is fine but you need angularjs >= 1.5.4